# in model hook, this.store.find() fails

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm doing this:

```
App.AccountsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('Account', {company: 'Blah'});
  }
});
```

but always get an error message:

```
Error while processing route: accounts Cannot read property 'map' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at s.map (http://localhost/public/bower_components/ember/ember.min.js:10:14956)
    at Ember.Object.extend.pushMany (http://localhost/public/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.min.js:10:6083)
    at c.extend.load (http://localhost/public/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.min.js:9:19306)
    at http://localhost/public/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.min.js:9:31635
    at a (http://localhost/public/bower_components/ember/ember.min.js:12:1824)
    at i (http://localhost/public/bower_components/ember/ember.min.js:12:1743)
    at c (http://localhost/public/bower_components/ember/ember.min.js:12:2476)
    at http://localhost/public/bower_components/ember/ember.min.js:13:11367
    at e.invoke (http://localhost/public/bower_components/ember/ember.min.js:11:24893)
    at Object.e.flush (http://localhost/public/bower_components/ember/ember.min.js:11:25401) ember.min.js:10
n.function.n.apply.r ember.min.js:10
A.error ember.min.js:18
i ember.min.js:18
s ember.min.js:19
e.trigger ember.min.js:19
(anonymous function) ember.min.js:19
a ember.min.js:12
i ember.min.js:12
h ember.min.js:12
(anonymous function) ember.min.js:13
e.invoke ember.min.js:11
e.flush ember.min.js:11
t.end ember.min.js:11
(anonymous function)
```

If I get rid of the query params, that is:

```
App.AccountsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('Account');
  }
});
```

then everything works ok.  I'm using ember 1.6.0 and ember-data 1.0.0-beta8.  I've tried a few different versions in case its a bug, but can't fix the problem.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: bad json response, would you mind adding the json that's being returned when you do it with the query?

Answer (score 0):

Your json response from a query/find all response should be a collection.  In your case it should look like this:

```
{
  accounts:[
    {
       id:1,
       company:'Blah'
    },
    {
       id:2,
       company:'Blah'
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Additionally you should be using lower case when passing in a type.

```
this.store.find('account');
```

Comment: But I don't get the chance to take a look at the result.  The error occurs before

Comment: it is making a request to the server?

Comment: ahhhhh, gotcha.  `findQuery` isn't supported in the fixture adapter, since this logic is handed off to the server.  You'd see it if you used the non-minified version of the code.  It'd yell `Assertion Failed: Not implemented: You must override the DS.FixtureAdapter::queryFixtures method to support querying the fixture store. Error: Assertion Failed: Not implemented: You must override the DS.FixtureAdapter::queryFixtures method to support querying the fixture store.` http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/815/edit

Comment: sooo... what's the workaround? It would seem silly to put static data in the server just to make it `findQuery`-able

Comment: findQuery just sends a list of items to the server to do the filtering logic, the rest adapter doesn't do any of the logic, so it doesn't make sense to have it implemented on the fixture adapter.  You'll just want to use this.store.filter when you want to do client side filtering...